# Numbers - "the index.xml file is missing"

Tags: macos, numbers, error

I am running OS X Yosemite on my Mac 10.10.5.  I have Numbers files saved.  When I try to open them, I get "The index.xml file is missing."  How do I open these files?

Comment: What versions of numbers do you have? This problem can stem from having multiple versions on your system. If you right click on the document is tthere multiple versions of numbers listed under "open with"? When did you make these files? How exactly?